# Convergence of a product using Fourier series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The function $f(x)=\cos{\alpha x}$ has period $2\pi$ and is defined by

$f(x)=\cos{\alpha x}$
$(-\pi <x \le \pi), \alpha \notin \mathbf{Z}$

Obtain the Fourier series of $f(x)$ and hence show that

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-\alpha^2}=\frac{1-\pi\alpha \cot{\pi\alpha}}{2\alpha^2}$

What result is obtained by letting $\alpha \rightarrow 0$ in this formula?

You may assume that $x\cot{x}=1-\frac{1}{3}x^2$ when $x$ is small.

Deduce that

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{1}{n^2(n^2-\alpha^2)}=\frac{1}{2\alpha^4}(1-\frac{\pi^2\alpha^2}{3}-\pi \alpha \cot{\pi \alpha}), \alpha \notin \mathbf{Z}$

---

The Fourier series is all fine

$\cos{\alpha x}=\frac{1}{\pi \alpha} \sin{\alpha \pi}-\frac{2\alpha \sin{\alpha \pi}}{\pi} \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2-\alpha^2} \cos{nx}$

Putting $x=\pi$ (pt of cty)

$\cos{\alpha \pi}-\frac{1}{\pi \alpha} \sin{\alpha \pi}=-\frac{2\alpha \sin{\alpha \pi}}{\pi} \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-\alpha^2}$

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{1}{n^2-\alpha^2}=\frac{1-\pi \alpha \cot{\pi \alpha}}{2\alpha^2}$

As $\alpha \rightarrow 0$,

$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}[\frac{1-\pi \alpha \cot{\pi \alpha}}{2\alpha^2}]$

$=\lim_{\alpha\rightarrow 0}[\frac{1-\pi(1-\frac{1}{3}\alpha^2}{2\alpha^2}]\frac{\pi}{6}$

And then , how do I prove the above product?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know of a function with Fourier coefficients $\hat{f}(n) = \frac{1}{n^2}$? If so, how would it be related to a function with Fourier coefficients $\hat{F}(n) = \frac{1}{n^2(n^2-\alpha^2)}$?

Hint:

> Convolution theorem.

Comment: A logical answer would be to multiply both.

Comment: That would be true when we're talking about the Fourier coefficients of the functions. But what about the functions themselves? If $f$ and $g$ are two functions, can you think of a function $F$ whose Fourier coefficients are $\hat{F}(n) = \hat{f}(n)\hat{g}(n)$?